# How is the split horizon rule used to prevent routing loops?

Tags: networking, routing

Can someone please explain how the split horizon rule is used to prevent loops in the network shown in the link below. I am learning this for the first time and am a little confused. I am using this as an example to help with my understanding.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split horizon just means you don't advertise learned routes back to who told you about them.

R1 would advertise 200.200.4.0 to R2, and R2 would learn that route and advertise it to its peers, but split-horizon will prevent the advertisement from being sent back to R1.

Comment: Okay, so when a router R2 sends its routing table information to router R3, R3 does not send back its routing tables to R2?

Comment: Also how does that prevent loops in the network? could you please explain with an example using the network above

Comment: This isn't something that can't be learned by way of some research. Here's a simple explanation with an example - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_horizon_route_advertisement

Comment: @joeqwerty yeah it is, but SO sent him over here (he mentioned it but it was edited out).  I figured it was better to answer than give him the double-boot.